# How to split a table in a report MS Access

Tags: ms-access, split, report

How do I split a table into two tables? For example, I have a form of classes (in school) and semi form of students that study in the same class (just first and last name), and made a report for this form that above there are the details of the class and below there is a table of all the students with their name and last name. I wanted to ask how do I split the table to not continue page number 2
if I have alot of students so when the table reach the end of the page it will continue on the other side of the page (small table)?

Comment: Your question is very difficult to read. Please try to edit your post with more correct spelling and grammar to get appropriate help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you actually want to split the tables if you are designing a report. What you want to do is adjust the report so that the field for Class the students are studying is in a group header. In design mode, click "add a group" and then select the Class field. Then below that is where you will want to put the first and last names in the detail part.

You can also adjust where the pages split and you will need to play around with the design view options to get exactly what you want.

Ultimately, I think you want your report to look something like this:

Geometry
Josetta
Scott
John
Mark

English
Scott
Josetta

History
John
Mark

Comment: look what i want to do http://imgur.com/7nu5x9S
i want that the continous of the table will be in the left side and without crossing the line

Comment: So you want this in 2 columns? You can add columns to the report, too.